# What does adding !important on the end of a CSS attribute do?

Tags: css, attributes, properties

Why do people add !important on the end of property declarations in their CSS, and what does it do for them?

For example, ever seen this?:

```
div{
    min-height:100px;
    height:auto !important;
    height:100px;
}
```

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules but I'm sure this is a dup

Comment: ...and you couldn't google this?!

Answer (score 4):

`!important` adds importance to a CSS rule so it will have more points to override another declaration with less points. For example:

```
div {
    color: red !important;
}

div#hello {
    color: black;
}
```

A `<div>` with ID "hello" would still be red.

Comment: The technical phrase you're looking for is "higher specificity."